# image processing - second order directional derivative

Tags: image, optimization, image-processing, filter, signals

to detect valleys, I would like to find the min values of my 2D signal in the direction along which signal has greatest magnitude of its second order derivative.

I think that I can calculate, on each pixel, the magnitude of second derivative w.r.t xx, yy, xy, yx, take the max of these, and see if my pixel is a local min in this direction.

First do you think that I am right when doing so?

Second, what are filters like to compute the directional derivative? I have an idea this is

001111100

001111100

001111100

00-2-2-2-2-2-200

00-2-2-2-2-2-200

00-2-2-2-2-2-200

001111100

001111100

001111100

for derivative along yy,

000000000

01110-1-1-10

01110-1-1-10

01110-1-1-10

000000000

0-1-1-101110

0-1-1-101110

0-1-1-101110

000000000

for derivative along xy, etc...

but I would like somebody to confirm, or to hint at relevant doc.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: You probably want something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying this:

1. Smooth: If the image might contain noise, I would filter it first with a Gaussian kernel since the second derivative is very noise sensitive.
2. Second derivative: filter the image with the discrete laplacian, e.g:
   0  1  0;
   1 -4  1;
   0  1  0
3. Find the local maximum of the second derivative:
   Dilate the image with this mask: 1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1

All three steps have ready implementations in OpenCV\Matlab.

Comment: thanks. I already tried the LoG filter before my find valley algo. However, what I want to find know is, for each pixel, direction for max second derivative (and test whether, in this direction, it is a local max). Maybe you can confirm me that the filters I propose are doing what I want: Lyy and Lxy. regards